GraalVM for Javafx on Netbeans, WIndows
I need help installing and connecting Graal VM for javafx in netbeans.
I want to create a project specifically in javafx, but only when the following sentence appears:
Nashorn was removed in Java 15, you must provide an engine to run JavaScript on your own. Currently, the preferred option is Graal VM JavaScript.
I have already found out that GraalVM is needed for this, and tried to install it. I downloaded it, connected the dependencies in the path environment variable, but still nothing works. when you run the "gu" command, the following message is displayed in the Windows command prompt:
"gu" is not an internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file.
Please tell me how to properly install this GraalVM and connect it to the project. training instructions on the Internet, including on official websites, do not help.
I have already tried to install GraalVM according to the instructions from the official website, but it still did not work, I tried to connect GraalVM via microsoft visual studio, but there were also errors during installation and connection.

I'm not familiar with [tag:graalvm], but you might review your NetBeans project type—inadvertently creating an [tag:ant] project, as seen here, "may attempt to package dependencies that are no longer required."

gu removed from graalvm, just for an example you can check this project which is maven project uses javafx and it compiles with graalvm

You don't need Graal VM or JavaScript to create a JavaFX project. This is likely an xy problem. To create a JavaFX project, follow the instructions at openjfx.io.
